# Differential and common mode over-range indicator for In-amp

Tags: comparator, instrumentation-amplifier

[image]

[image]

I need some advice with differential and common-mode over-range indication. I have a device with In-amp and I would like to add a Led or buzzer for differential and common-mode over-range indication. I have easy access to all nodes as this In-amp is not an IC but 3 separate op-amps. The device is powered from SMPS with +/- 6.5V rails. My initial thought is to use two window comparators. The first one using Va as input and the second using Vb as input. I would use a potential divider to set Vref_high at approx. 3V and Vref_low at approx. -3V using existing power rail from SMPS (Vref should not drift). One thing I do not like about this solution is the fact that I would have to use an additional quad op-amp IC. I am wondering if there is a simpler solution to my problem.

Comment: For differential over-voltage use the InAmp output as an indication of how bad it might be. For CM, just use one input or, use steering diodes from both input lines. If this doesn't make sense then maybe you need to put some numerical cases into your question.

Comment: Thank you I will ad some numbers. Probing one point for CM and using the output as Diff sounds good (would save 2 op-amps). Would still have to combine both Diff and CM signals to connect to the same indication device. Regarding steering diodes how exactly should I connect them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "few" resistors and diodes added and only the two extra op. amps. would be acceptable?

[image]

The initial idea would be to monitor if any of the 3 op. amp. outputs go above or below the 2 voltage references. It would not be very precise due to the diode voltage drops.

[image]

The diodes are available in "pairs":

[image]